# Check if file size is changing with Windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a little problem I'm trying to sort out. I'm recording sound 24/7 and they are split in .wav files that have 2 hour duration. Since .wav files are pretty large I would like to encode them to .mp3. Everything works fine with this script

```
@echo off
cd path/to/folder

for %%i in (*.wav) do (
   lame.exe %%i
   del %%i
)
```

Everything works as it should but there is one problem, I want to check if file is still recording, if that's true then I don't want to encode it. I tried to check file size now and 10 sec later but it gets same value. Here is example

```
@echo off
cd path/to/folder

for %%i in (*.wav) do (
    echo %%~zi
    ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 >nul
    echo %%~zi
)
```

output is for example:

444444

and after 10 sec same

444444.

Can someone please tell me how to check file size if it's constantly changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this on your files.

It will get a filename (sorted alphabetically in NTFS) and test to see if it is locked, and loop if it is - testing every 60 seconds.

When the file is free it will launch lame and then check the next file.

```
@echo off
cd /d "path/to/folder"

for %%a in (*.wav) do call :next "%%a"
echo done
pause
goto :eof

:next
set "filename=%~1"
:loop
2>nul (call;>>"%filename%") && (
  echo "%filename%" is free! & goto :lame
) || (
  echo "%filename%" is in use or is read only!
)
timeout /t 60 /nobreak
goto :loop
:lame
  lame.exe "%~1"
  del "%~1"
```